# Securing minifi c++ agent against remote NIFI

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-minifi

I have a remote 3 node secure NIFI server to which I want to send some data via MINIFI C++ agent. I am trying to understand the mechanics of generating and signing certificates for MINIFI (client) but I am not able to find detailed documentation.

I see the below configs:

```
#nifi.security.need.ClientAuth=
#nifi.security.client.certificate=
#nifi.security.client.private.key=
#nifi.security.client.pass.phrase=
#nifi.security.client.ca.certificate=
```

but how do I generate a client.pem and sign it?

**EDIT**:
This is what I tried to do (self-sign), but this fails with:

```
[2020-08-14 07:19:08.872] [org::apache::nifi::minifi::utils::HTTPClient] [error] curl_easy_perform() failed SSL connect error

[2020-08-14 07:19:08.872] [org::apache::nifi::minifi::RemoteProcessorGroupPort] [error] ProcessGroup::refreshRemoteSite2SiteInfo -- curl_easy_perform() failed
```

```
cd $HOME
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -keyout machine.key -out machine.csr
openssl x509 -req -sha256 -days 365 -in machine.csr -signkey machine.key -out machine.pem

###
Downloaded the public certificate from the server into ---> $HOME/server.crt


nifi.security.need.ClientAuth=true
nifi.security.client.certificate=$HOME/machine.pem
nifi.security.client.private.key=$HOME/machine.key
nifi.security.client.pass.phrase=password
nifi.security.client.ca.certificate=$HOME/server.crt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to generate an X.509 certificate and sign it ([openssl](https://www.openssl.org/), [TinyCert](https://www.tinycert.org/), [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/), [NiFi TLS Toolkit](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/toolkit-guide.html#tls_toolkit), etc.). The important requirement is that the certificate is either *explicitly trusted* (the public certificate is imported into the NiFi truststore) or *implicitly trusted* (any of the public certificates in the signing chain are present in the NiFi truststore).

One approach is to follow the [walkthrough for deploying a secure NiFi cluster](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/walkthroughs.html#creating-and-securing-a-nifi-cluster-with-the-tls-toolkit) and use the TLS Toolkit to generate a client keystore, then [export the certificate and key from that keystore to PEM format using these commands](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/toolkit-guide.html#additional_certificate_commands).

Comment: How do I get the host of NIFI CA?
```
tls-toolkit.sh client -h ------>

-c,--certificateAuthorityHostname <arg> Hostname of NiFi Certificate Authority (default: localhost)
```

Comment: This is determined by you; set it to whatever you want, but that certificate name will be used to sign any following "leaf" certificates. Either run a single command which generates all the certs, or continue running the individual commands in the same directory and it will reference the same CA cert to sign them.